# Android Studio: Shared preference login page still showing and loading on SharedPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

When I'm logging in on my app my I want my login page will not show anymore if the user is already logged in before. Because everytime a user terminates the app and opens the app again the login page will show with the loading message. I want to implement it because if the user opens the app without data connection the user will still go to his page.

Well here is my code.

```
pref = getSharedPreferences("Login.conf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = pref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("hasLoggedIn", true);
editor.commit();

boolean hasLoggedIn = pref.getBoolean("hasLoggedIn", false);

if(hasLoggedIn){
    String username = pref.getString("username", "");
    String password = pref.getString("password", "");

    if (!username.equals("") && (!password.equals(""))) {
        postData.put("username", username);
        postData.put("password", password);
        authenticate(postData);
    }

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etUsername.getText().toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etPassword.getText().toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Password is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            editor = pref.edit();
            postData.put("username", etUsername.getText().toString());
            postData.put("password", MD5.encrypt(etPassword.getText().toString()));
            editor.commit();
            authenticate(postData);
        }
    });
}
```

## authenticate

```
private void authenticate(final HashMap<String, String> postData){
    PostResponseAsyncTask task1 = new PostResponseAsyncTask(LoginActivity.this, postData,
            new AsyncResponse() {
                @Override
                public void processFinish(String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, s);
                    if (s.contains("renter")) {
                        // Login success, Save to prefs
                        editor = pref.edit();
                        editor.clear();
                        editor.putString("username", postData.get("username"));
                        editor.putString("password", postData.get("password"));
                        editor.putString("userlevel", s);
                        editor.commit();

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Renter Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RenterTabs.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                        finish();

                    } else if (s.contains("owner")) {
                        // Login success, Save to prefs
                        editor = pref.edit();
                        editor.clear();
                        editor.putString("username", postData.get("username"));
                        editor.putString("password", postData.get("password"));
                        editor.putString("userlevel", s);
                        editor.commit();

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Owner Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, OwnerTabs.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                        finish();
                    } else if (s.contains("driver")) {
                        editor = pref.edit();
                        editor.clear();
                        editor.putString("username", postData.get("username"));
                        editor.putString("password", postData.get("password"));
                        editor.putString("userlevel", s);
                        editor.commit();

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Driver Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DriverTabs.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                        finish();
                    }else if(s.contains("-1")){
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Wrong username or password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    task1.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/carkila/authenticate.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I've understood so far is, you want to click the login button automatically when some user is already logged in your application before using the username and the password stored in the `SharedPreferences`. So if I'm assuming the problem correctly, here's how you can implement this.

I'm just rewriting your code. See the comments for better understanding.

```
pref = getSharedPreferences("Login.conf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
boolean hasLoggedIn = pref.getBoolean("hasLoggedIn", false);

// Move the onClickListener outside the if statement 
// Because, if the user is not already logged in 
// Then you need to have a click action on this button. 
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etUsername.getText().toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etPassword.getText().toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Password is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        editor = pref.edit();
        postData.put("username", etUsername.getText().toString());
        postData.put("password", MD5.encrypt(etPassword.getText().toString()));
        editor.commit();
        authenticate(postData);
    }
});

if(hasLoggedIn) {
    String username = pref.getString("username", "");
    String password = pref.getString("password", "");

    // Remove this
    // if (!username.equals("") && (!password.equals(""))) {
    //    postData.put("username", username);
    //    postData.put("password", password);
    //    authenticate(postData);
    // }

    // Simply put this in here 
    btnLogin.performClick();
}
```

And save the preference after a successful login in the `authenticate` function

```
private void authenticate(...) {

    // On a successful login
    editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("hasLoggedIn", true);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: When i removed the if of the `if (!username.equals("") && (!password.equals("")))` every time I go back to my app it toasts that username is empty.

Comment: Try uninstall and reinstalling your application. Because, you may have stored empty strings already in your preference. And please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why should `if(hasLoggedIn)` line ever be negative. You always put a `true` value in `hasLoggedIn` shared preferences and then you have an if statement on that.